# Can we integrate multi-tenant azure application (daemon app) with SAML? If yes, how?

Tags: azure, oauth, single-sign-on, saml, multi-tenant

We have a multitenant azure app (Daemon app) that connects with the client's outlook services, through graph API when a scheduler is triggered. No user sign-in is required.
We successfully integrated this multi-tenant app with OAuth clients using admin consent URL and Microsoft graph library(java)

Now, we have a client who is on SAML, but doesn't want to use OAuth (not sure why)

Going through documentation, I found SAML is supported with single sign-on but we don't have a user login since it is a backend scheduler job.

I am trying to find out if there is a way to integrate this app with a SAML client.

Can someone please guide me on how to integrate this same app with SAML?

Note: I am a java developer and new to SAM, AAD.
A detailed explanation would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-sso

Answer (score 0):

•   Yes, you can surely **configure your multi-tenant Azure AD app with SAML for your Java web app by using the federation metadata document that is published through the registered application’s endpoints** as shown below in the snapshot. Thus, since your **application is multi-tenant registered, the tenant endpoint is independent and the ‘tenandomainname’ is ‘common’**: -

[image: Azure AD App endpoints]

Thus, then in your Java application, you will have to ***reference the concerned registered multi-tenant application for helping to reach out the users accessing this Java application for authentication purposes to Azure AD as shown in the code below in the ‘application.properties’ file under ‘src/main/resources’***: -

```
  aad.clientId=Enter_the_Application_Id_here
```

aad.authority=https://login.microsoftonline.com/Enter_the_Tenant_Info_Here/

```
  aad.secretKey=Enter_the_Client_Secret_Here
  aad.redirectUriSignin=http://localhost:8080/msal4jsample/secure/aad
  aad.redirectUriGraph=http://localhost:8080/msal4jsample/graph/me
```

Thus, accordingly, when the **user through the java web app tries to login with in-house credentials to Azure AD, then the SAML client configured for federation with Azure AD by configuring a RPT (Relying Party Trust) in it will facilitate the authentication and token grant scenarios**. Also, getting an **access token using Azure Active Directory’s Graph API can help to authenticate a user with an application or API** as below: -

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
AuthenticationContext context = new AuthenticationContext(AUTHORITY, false, service);
Future<AuthenticationResult> future = context.acquireToken(
"https://graph.windows.net", YOUR_TENANT_ID, username, password,
null);
AuthenticationResult result = future.get();
System.out.println("Access Token - " + result.getAccessToken());
System.out.println("Refresh Token - " + result.getRefreshToken());
System.out.println("ID Token - " + result.getIdToken());
```

For more information regarding setting up a SAML client for federated authentication with Azure AD, kindly refer to the below links: -

***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/direct-federation***

***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/activedirectory?view=azure-java-stable#example***

***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-sign-user-app-configuration?tabs=java#configuration-files***